# Capitalising in Sublime Text 2 snippets

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am trying to set up snippets for getters and setters in C++. This is what I have:

```xml
<snippet>
     <description>getter</description>
     <content><![CDATA[
        ${1:(type)} get${2:(var)}() { return ${2:}; }
     ]]></content>
     <tabTrigger>getter</tabTrigger>
     <scope>source.c, source.objc, source.c++, source.objc++</scope>
</snippet>
```

However, I like to use camel case. Is there a way in which to capitalise the first letter after “get” but not capitalise it in the return statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.  First field will be `type`, fill that in, then tab to the next spot and enter your variable name.

```xml
<snippet>
     <description>getter</description>
     <content><![CDATA[
${1:type} get${2/./\U${0}\E/}() { return ${2:}; }
$0]]></content>
     <tabTrigger>getter</tabTrigger>
     <scope>source.c, source.objc, source.c++, source.objc++</scope>
</snippet>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]